# Textarea to plain text mail, problem with line breaks

Tags: php, email, textarea, line-breaks

In a form for ordering I give some option to add a few remarks. The people involved so far used e-mail for ordering and in practice they  added a lot of remarks beside the actual order.
The form has a textarea. When I enter

```
 Dit is een oefening.
Komt de mail
a) wel aan
b) geeft hij de juiste weergave?
```

the textarea posted in PHP is shown as:

`Dit is een oefening.\r\nKomt de mail\r\na) wel aan\r\nb) geeft hij de juiste weergave?`

So far so good, I thought.
But in the mail the text does not break as intended, is exactly reproduced as that string

> Dit is een oefening.\r\nKomt de mail\r\na) wel aan\r\nb) geeft hij de juiste weergave?

Is there some way (preferably an easy one) I can format such a text string to do as intended?

The string($xtravraag) is included in a line
`if ($xtravraag != '') {$emailvraagk = "\r\n MAILBERICHT BIJ BESTELLING \r\n\r\n $xtravraag";} else {$emailvraagk = '';}`

I already tried this one, that completely messes up the result:
`if ($xtravraag != '') {$emailvraagk = "\r\n".' MAILBERICHT BIJ BESTELLING'."\r\n\r\n".$xtravraag;} else {$emailvraagk = '';}`

leads to

> \r\n MAILBERICHT BIJ BESTELLING \r\n\r\n $xtravraag

and that header originally worked fine.

Mail headers include:

```
        'Mime-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
        'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .         
        'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion()
```

*Removing the transfer-encoding is no option. It is needed for the diacritics that are frequently used. That demands UTF-8.*

### As requested the code within the pages

```
 <fieldset><legend>Overige vragen of opmerkingen die geen bestelling zijn</legend>
  <textarea name='xtravraag' id='xtravraag' cols='76' rows='5'> </textarea>
  </fieldset>
```

Then posted

```
if (isset($_POST['xtravraag'])) {$xtravraag = $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['xtravraag']));} else{$xtravraag='';}
echo  "extravraag: $xtravraag <br>";        //MOET WEG BIJ OPLEVERING
```

*and that includes the echo that showed the full line*

### solved

the `real_escape_string` did a foul trick here.

Comment: are you using double `"` or single `'` quotes when you add the message to the variable used in the mail function?

Comment: I used double quotes originally. Thanks for that hint, I tried immediately. Changing to sinqle quotes alas did not work; splitting it up like how it works perfect for the lines of the form makes it worse even.
adapted the examples.

Comment: Can you include the full code used to read the textarea and send the email?

Comment: Do not use `real_escape_string`. Use prepared statements instead. It could be the cause of your current problem.

Comment: I agree that `real_escape_string` looks to be the culprit here

Comment: Thanks guys! That did it :)
and since the string has no other function than just being added to that e-mail, I dare to omit the ```real_escape_string```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime `mail()` function is not rendering the `"\r\n"` line breaks correctly, you could try to make it multiple lines like this :

```php
if ($xtravraag != '') {$emailvraagk = "
 MAILBERICHT BIJ BESTELLING 

 $xtravraag";} else {$emailvraagk = '';}
```

Or use the `PHP_EOL` to enable the cross-platform support :

```php
if ($xtravraag != '') {$emailvraagk = PHP_EOL." MAILBERICHT BIJ BESTELLING ".PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL." $xtravraag";} else {$emailvraagk = '';}
```

Comment: I doubt if that is the case here, 
So far that went OK, it's just the line breaks **within** the string $xtravraag that malfunction.

Answer (score -1):

Try formatting your textarea content with php `nl2br()` function.

Comment: That would just embed `<br />` tags into the email as it's plain text: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: oh sorry, my bad !